# Using a movieClip as a variable

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Previously in my code, I had a Variable, Chip. Chip moved around the screen and everything was fine.

```
var chip:Shape= new Shape();
chip.graphics.lineStyle(0,0);
chip.graphics.beginFill(0x3333FF,0.8);
chip.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,10);
chip.graphics.endFill();
```

was the code to make chip.  Now I've make a movieClip and I would like to use the movie clip instead, so I know I'd start with something like

```
var chip:movieClip;
```

but I'm lost after that. How would I be able to use him in place of making the shape?

Comment: Why are you lost now? Why were you not lost when doing it with the `Shape` object? Post the code that you are using!

Comment: The question implies a deep misunderstanding of objects and variables. Variables are not object and objects cannot be variables.

Comment: movieClips are containers (for many things including **Shapes**). They also have a timeline so you can travel to different frames of that movieClip. You likely want `var chip:movieClip = new movieClip;` and from there use `.x` or `.y` to position it. To add content into movieClip use `addChild`.

Comment: That's typically what not to do with a MovieClip VC One. Can you add any frames to your MovieClip? nope so in that example a Sprite is indicated.

Answer (score 0):

So I'd guess that you are using Flash IDE and have created a movieclip for your Chip that is now in your library and you don't know how to add it to the stage :)

Right-click on your movieclip in the library and select "Properties". In the advanced section select the "Export for actionscript" checkbox and give your movieclip a linkage name in the "Class" Input field, for example "Chip". Leave the "Base name" as MovieClip.

Now your movieclip is accessible via actionscript and you could add it to your stage:

```
var chip:ChipMC = new ChipMC();
addChild(chip);

trace(chip.x, chip.y);
```